# How to check for android resources that are missing default values?

Tags: android, lint

I am curious about how to find android resources that are missing default values.  For example, it is possible to define `corner_radius` in `dimens-sw600dp.xml`, without defining it in `dimens.xml`.  This would cause a runtime crash on any device whose smallest width is less than 600 dp.

In the above example, it's not obvious that the default value is missing.  After aapt runs, you are able to reference the dimension in code and in xml, despite  the missing default value.  (via `R.dimen.corner_radius` and `@dimen/corner_radius`).  The error is not discoverable until runtime.

Android Studio includes a lint check for missing translations, but doesn't seem to check for other resource types.  Is there an easy way to check for other missing resources (dimens, layout, etc.) at build time?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Faced the same problem, it was hard to find missing resource.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene Unfortunately, still do not have a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now depend on the `MissingDefaultResource` lint rule (found [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)):

> If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
>   and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values etc),
>   then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a device where the
>   device is in a configuration missing the given qualifier.
>
> As a special case, drawables do not have to be specified in the base folder;
>   if there is a match in a density folder (such as drawable-mdpi) that image
>   will be used and scaled. Note however that if you  only specify a drawable in
>   a folder like drawable-en-hdpi, the app will crash in non-English locales.
>
> There may be scenarios where you have a resource, such as a -fr drawable,
>   which is only referenced from some other resource with the same qualifiers
>   (such as a -fr style), which itself has safe fallbacks. However, this still
>   makes it possible for somebody to accidentally reference the drawable and
>   crash, so it is safer to create a default dummy fallback in the base folder.
>   Alternatively, you can suppress the issue by adding
>   tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource" on the element.
>
> (This scenario frequently happens with string translations, where you might
>   delete code and the corresponding resources, but forget to delete a
>   translation. There is a dedicated issue id for that scenario, with the id
>   ExtraTranslation.)

Comment: Can any Cordova users weigh in on how to fix the issues identified by Lint? I see warnings in the form "The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder" but when I attempt to add <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen.png" /> the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate Cache and restart should solve the problem
Check the Clear file system cache

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found one way, not the best, but it's working.

Delete all other `dimens.xml` files, except main one (i.e. `v19, w820dp` etc).

After that just build your project - you will get a list of errors where dimension is missing now.
When you found problems, just revert deletion.