# The layout <layout> in layout has no declaration in the base layout folder [error]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am getting the following error in Android Studio on my app's layout:

> The layout  in layout has no declaration in the base layout
> folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a
> configuration that does not match this qualifier

One of the layouts that I am getting this error is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@null" >

      <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/loading_top" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/loading_bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/loading_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@null" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I get the error on the first line of the first LinearLayout.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Thank you

**UPDATE: Answered my question with what has resolved the problem for me**

Comment: @L Kemp once show me u r logcat

Comment: @Varma actually the app runs without error. I just can see the error once I open the xml file, but the layout of this xml file runs normally

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated since API 8 and replaced with match_parent  [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Comment: @MahdiJavaheri Thank you for your advice, however, I've already known that, I am removing that deprecated code little by little.

Comment: In my case it was issue related to filename, you can also check by renaming your file in small caps

Comment: I renamed file and got this issue. The most annoying thing i have ever seen in android studio.

Comment: Try to build first, I got the same issue after creating layout but after I build it disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had copied the xml files in the folder using Windows Explorer. It seems to have caused an encoding issue.
After deleting the files and coping them inside Android Studio, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 361):

In my case **closing and reopening Android studio** solved the problem. Rebuilding the project or clearing the cache didn't help.

Comment: I am seeing this every time I add a new layout file. Restarting/rebuilding fixes it but did anyone found root cause of it?

Comment: Note that Build > Clean Project resolved the issue for me.

Comment: For me also, clean, rebuild nothing worked. Just closing and re-opening Android studio fixed this issue.

Comment: Closing and reopening the project solved the problem for me (I didn't have to restart the Android Studio altogether)

Answer (score 95):

You can also try this :

File => Invalidate Caches / Restart => Invalidate and Restart.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, it helps, but strange, that in previous versions Build > Rebuild Project helped. They crashed something.

Comment: I added one plus to you, as your solutions works for AS 3.2 (in my case without Eclipse).

Answer (score 32):

Invalidate Cache / Restart solved my problem.

Answer (score 24):

I just did `Build > Clean Project`

Comment: Or `Build > Rebuild Project`.

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was the use of capital letters in the file name. I left everything in lowercase and it was fixed.

Comment: This was my issue. What a weird bug. Just made it lowercase and all was good.

Answer (score 16):

If you devise your layout :
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
....

you should add layout by default
like this:

[image]

Comment: This was the solution for me, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I received this error **when moving layout files between Gradle modules**.  I didn't have to go so far as to **invalidate caches** as it resolved itself when I restarted `Android Studio` and **cleaned the project**.  It seems likely to be an **IDE bug**.

Answer (score 6):

In my case i resolved that with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662406/how-to-check-for-android-resources-that-are-missing-default-values):

the Android say me this *id-error:[MissingDefaultResource](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)* as documentation say:

> If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or
>   -en, and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a
>   device where the device is in a configuration missing the given
>   qualifier.
>
> As a special case, drawables do not have to be specified in the base
>   folder; if there is a match in a density folder (such as
>   drawable-mdpi) that image will be used and scaled. Note however that
>   if you only specify a drawable in a folder like drawable-en-hdpi, the
>   app will crash in non-English locales.
>
> There may be scenarios where you have a resource, such as a -fr
>   drawable, which is only referenced from some other resource with the
>   same qualifiers (such as a -fr style), which itself has safe
>   fallbacks. However, this still makes it possible for somebody to
>   accidentally reference the drawable and crash, so it is safer to
>   create a default dummy fallback in the base folder. Alternatively, you
>   can suppress the issue by adding tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource"
>   on the element.
>
> (This scenario frequently happens with string translations, where you
>   might delete code and the corresponding resources, but forget to
>   delete a translation. There is a dedicated issue id for that scenario,
>   with the id ExtraTranslation.)

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource" <!--this-->
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

But this is the easy solution, 'cause you make missing the resourse in Android.

I resolve this with ***file system*** option. If *Android* tell you about missing resourse meaning some thing is missing and you should replenish that.

**you should be go to \app\src\main\res**

maybe: right click in file's missing folder, show in Exporer,and go back to \app\src\main\res

You should be find

```
/layout

/layout-normal

/layout-large

/some more folders
```

You should be find where do the files is missing. In my case that's missing in /layout

Answer (score 6):

Press- 'ctrl+A' --> 'ctrl+x' --> 'ctrl+v') this does not change anything but apparently solves the errors.

Comment: Initially I thought this is a dumb answer but this worked for me. Hail Android Studio gods.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this issue was caused by Uppercase letter. Wrong chars like "-" can also cause the issue.
I changed the name from `Activity_disease.xml` to `activity_disease.xml` and the issue fixed.

Answer (score 5):

For me it occured because I had accidentally named the file with a spacebar rather than underline, i.e `fragment_item summary.xml` rather than `fragment_item_summary.xml`.

Comment: This question has been answered 2 years ago. The problem was related to file encoding, not a space bar issue. So I am voting to close it.

Comment: i had a dash instead of an underscore in the file name, and got this error

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me like rebuilding the project or Invalidating the cache. In my case **closing and reopening Android studio solved the problem**.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by just syncing project with gradle

Answer (score 2):

**Note** that when you are using different versions of layout like (**Large/Small/Nornal**) then that case you have to same main layout folder. like this way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case it seems that Google used to expect (or at least accept) different names between different layouts; I had a `time_dialog.xml` and a `time_dialog_landscape.xml`. Renaming the latter to `time_dialog.xml` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following steps made it work:

1. Cut all the code out of the page (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for windows)
2. Paste the code back.

Comment: Something I did for a similar problem in `strings.xml` too, I agree with this one

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue after copy/pasting code into an XML layout file, but I fixed it by just manually creating the file.
Very strange, since the code was exactly the same, but somehow it fixed this issue.
I did try restarting and doing the "File => Invalidate Caches / Restart => Invalidate and Restart" fix, but the issue was only fixed by manually recreating the file.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the previous post, I had to rename the resource. I created it initially by copy-pasting an `.xml` file in the project explorer. Confusingly this had the same name in the explorer but with a `land` dimmed attribute associated with the layout.

My solution was to go into the file system and manually move the file from the `layout-land` to `layout` folder

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be happening because studio or compiler is not able to find the resource file inside the base layout folder. To solve the problem you might need to create the file into different layout folders. If you are using layout folders v21, v25 etc. folders for designing layouts for different target devices then you also might need to place your resource files there too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this warning appeared due to "wrong" character (dot) used in value name:

```
<dimen name="dp.divider.xlarge">24dp</dimen>
```

Removing dots (right click on a name, then Refactor-Rename in Android Studio) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but My case is different from above.

I just **renamed the resource** and it started working.

Actually my resource name was ic_menu_black_24dp.xml so it was conflicting with the android's menu resource.

Comment: it shouldn't conflict, since the system resources are in a different namespace, and even if they were, overriding with your local copy should have been fine.

Comment: Actually I got the same error as the OP it was due to other reasonsnot listed above so I resolved it by above step.I had posted this incase someone faces issue like mine may get help.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to remove the id attribute

```
android:id="@+id/[id same as filename]"
```

from the layout resource.

Answer (score 0):

(1)  Delete the original layout.

(2)  Add the layout again.

[Step-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyZr0.png)

[Step-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQQV5.png)

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me:

In Android Studio, right-click on the filename in the layout directory, and choose **Reformat code**, with no special tickbox selected on the next screen.

Not sure what exactly goes on under the hood here, but that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same error was showing because layout-land file and layout filename was different.

My Case:
layout-land -> my_layout_land
layout -> my_layout

I solved it by making both filenames the same. Because if you are using layout-land and you have a file in layout-land then you must have a file in layout folder also.

Answer (score 0):

You may have incremental build enabled so temporarily disable it and the error will go away. That's what was happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Clean build was enough for me.

Answer (score -4):

Placing `tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource"` in the screen layout description solved it for me.

Comment: +1 This actually works, at least before you Rebuild your project. Invalidate Cache / Closing and Reopening Android studio takes a lot of time especially on bigger projects, so this seems like a good temporary fix until you rebuild or restart your Android Studio.