# "The layout has no declaration in the base layout folder"

Tags: android, layout

My app only supports `landscape` mode (this is a business demand).

I have a layout xml file in the `layout-land` folder, but I did *not* bother to create a `layout` folder, since I explicitly disable portrait mode in the Android manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

and yet in my layout xml file I get the said warning in mentioned in title (the app runs just fine despite the warning).

Is this just Android studio being stupid because it doesn't see that portrait is disabled in the manifest file? Can I safely disregard this warning? Or should I actually change something?

---

Also, as a side question, is there any way to *make* `landscape` the base orientation?" This whole warning stems from the fact that `portrait` is the base orientation, and if I can somehow make `landscape` the base orientation, then this warning will probably just go away.

Comment: You have changed orientation correctly and there isn't error there.

Answer (score 8):

I added an empty activity on a project to encounter this error message.

To fix it, go to Android Studio(version 4.1.2), select File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart...

Comment: actually this solution still save me.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and remove all text from **build.gradle** sync it, after paste build.gradle content, sync again this error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The warning isn't related to screenOrientation. See here for handling this warning:

[The layout <layout> in layout has no declaration in the base layout folder [error]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52547657/12478830)

Comment: I already read that post. In my case, I am NOT migrating from eclipse. I tried every solution mentioned in the post you linked but none of them makes my warning go away.

Comment: That question and answer are for Android Studio too. @kc_dev

Comment: I'm don't mean to be buggy, but which answer in that post are you referring to? So far I've done: 1 All files are already in lower case 2 Clean Project 3 Invalidate cache 4 Restart Android Studio  but none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0):

I am starting in this world and I got the same message when creating a landscape layout, the error generated was the same as you comment and I solved it by putting the same name of the main layout, when doing this it generated a folder within the layout called the same name of the activitys_main and the error was solved.